# Ajax success not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

follow code is supposed to show alert msg. It is doing nothing. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong. Everything is working nicely execpt alert().

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    var baseUrl = document.location.origin;

 $(".ProductRemove").click(function(){
   var row_id = $(this).attr('id');
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    url:baseUrl+"/shop/api/cart",
    data:"row_id="+row_id+"&action=remove",    // multiple data sent using ajax
    success: function () {

          alert('success');

    },
    error: function(){
   alert('failure');
 }
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: If it's "doing nothing", the ajax method isn't even being called, which means your event handler isn't being triggered or there's an obvious error in your console.

Comment: It is removing data from server

Comment: And the error alert isn't occurring? Are you sure clicking ProductRemove isn't submitting some kind of form?

Comment: I am clicking ProductRemove as it is an ON CLICK event. It is neither showing "success" nor "failure" as alert.

Comment: Open your console.

Comment: Basically... It's not possible for jQuery's $.ajax to run without calling success/error unless you're either 1: redirecting before the ajax request has completed, or 2: not running the ajax request at all. Based on your symptoms, i'd expect you to be having problem #1. Remember, clicking on an anchor tag, by default, directs the page to it's href value. Clicking on a button that is inside a form, by default, will submit the form. Both of which would result in success/error not occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,
I got the solution. It is calling error function instead of success because I am returning in nothing from the server.

In ajax empty is not considered as JSON data. So to fix that I have to echo "json_encode(NULL);" in my server.